# Python - a more elegant solution?

Tags: solution

This produces the desired output BUT I can see that it is not an elegant solution (repetition of three similar for loops). How can this be condensed? How far can it be condensed to make it as short/elegant a solution as possible? Thanks in advance

```
for planet in range(1): #this produces the rows (is this line needed?)


    for column in range(1,6): #this produces the numbers
        print(column, end="***") 
    print()
    for column in range(6,11):
        print(column,end="***")
    print()
    for column in range(11,15):
        print(column,end="***")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
for item in range(1,16):
    if item % 5 == 0:
        print(item, "***", sep='')
        continue

    print(item, "***", sep='',end='')
```

It also returns the same result.

```
1***2***3***4***5***
6***7***8***9***10***
11***12***13***14***15***
```

You can also just substitute variables in the function to make it more readable and if you need to modify the number of rows & columns.

```
numColumns = 5
numValues = 15

for item in range(1,numValues+1):
    if item % numColumns == 0:  # If it is the last column in the row
        print(item, "***", sep='')  # Print the final column and a newline character (the default end character)
        continue  # Last column in row, skip the rest of the for loop and return to beginning

    print(item, "***", sep='',end='')  # Print the first few columns without a newline end character


# in the print() function:
#  'sep' is the separator between items in the print() function
#  'end' is the special character at the end of the print statement, which is by default the newline '\n'
```

Comment: Thanks so much - awesome! I hadn't come across the 'sep' command. What exactly does it do?

Comment: In the print() function, there is a space printed between the item and the "***". The 'sep' flag just replaces the space with 'no space'. I'll update my answer with comments for the flags.